# Recode pinescript tradingview to version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

There is a script SuperTrend BF , but it does not automatically recode in pinescript, because he is not familiar with lines 14 and 15, namely dotcolor. Help fix it to work in version 5. thank you

```
//SuperTrend - Originally by Olivier Seban
//Programmed by BlindFreddy 
//Blog: http://blindfreddy.postagon.com
study(title="SuperTrend BF", overlay = true)
Length = input(10, minval=1),
mult = input(3, type=float,minval=1)
avgTR = atr(Length)
newshortband = hl2 + avgTR * mult
newlongband = hl2 - avgTR * mult
longband=close[1]>=longband[1]? max(newlongband,longband[1]):newlongband
shortband = close[1]<=shortband[1]? min(newshortband,shortband[1]) : newshortband
trend = close > shortband[1] ? 1: close< longband[1]? -1: nz(trend[1],1)
supt = trend==1? longband: shortband
dotcolor = trend==1? green: maroon
plot(supt, color= dotcolor , style=circles, linewidth=3,title="SuperTrend")
```

I put //version3 changed study to indicator and transcoded to v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a [variable reassignment](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html?#variable-reassignment)

Something like that:

```
//@version=3
//SuperTrend - Originally by Olivier Seban
//Programmed by BlindFreddy 
//Blog: http://blindfreddy.postagon.com
study(title="SuperTrend BF", overlay = true)

//<set initial values>
longband = 0.0
shortband = 0.0
trend = 0.0

Length = input(10, minval=1),
mult = input(3, type=float,minval=1)
avgTR = atr(Length)
newshortband = hl2 + avgTR * mult
newlongband = hl2 - avgTR * mult
longband :=close[1]>=longband[1]? max(newlongband,longband[1]):newlongband
shortband := close[1]<=shortband[1]? min(newshortband,shortband[1]) : newshortband
trend := close > shortband[1] ? 1: close< longband[1]? -1: nz(trend[1],1)
supt = trend==1? longband: shortband
dotcolor = trend==1? green: maroon
plot(supt, color= dotcolor , style=circles, linewidth=3,title="SuperTrend")
```